# F# Splitting a list

Tags: list, split, f#, tuples

I am new to F# & tuples and I am trying to split a list into three lists of tuples using recursion and matching.

For example, a list of [1; 2; 3] would return:

```
l1 = [1] 
l2 = [2]
l3 = [3]
```

or

[1;2;3;4;5;6;7]:

```
l1 = [1;2;3]
l2 = [4; 5]
l3 = [6; 7]
```

So far my code starts out as

```
let rec split x =
    match x with
    | _ -> [], [], []
```

I'm not sure where to start when inserting elements into each list.

Comment: I get the impression that there is some confusion here, and I'm not entirely sure it's just me. The `[1, 2, 3]` is a list with a single element which is a three-tuple. The `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` is a list with a single element which is a seven-tuple. Likewise `l1`, `l2` and `l3` are all lists with just single elements that are tuples of various _arities_. The match returns tuples of lists. I suspect you confuse use of semicolon with use of colon. I'm not sure you understand what a tuple is. Tuples of various arities are not type compatible.

Comment: To put it simple, if what you are attempting to do is to make a function that do the same as `List.splitInto`, then tuples are not involved at all, so forget about them for now. You need to replace all commas with semicolons so that you have the actual list elements you want for this exercise, and then work your way from there.

Comment: @BentTranberg I assumed in my answer that the commas are a typo and that Alpha wants a list of numbers not a list with a single tuple as input.

Comment: @BitTickler ah yes, that was a typo. I did mean the semicolons. Thank you

Comment: As an aside: People coming from imperative languages usually approach this problem by mutation (start with count empty lists, then start filling them up). This makes it difficult for them to see how it can be done in a functional language: Build a list of chunks, where each chunk is the first n, the second n, the third n,... elements of the input list.

Comment: The edited question still seems to show confusion between lists and tuples.  The best course of action is probably to revert the question to its previous state (so the comments and answers make sense) and then ask a new question based on your new understanding.

Comment: It is still unclear what the list to 3-tuple of lists pattern is. Could you please expand your examples  say from 4 to 10 or 12 items to see the split pattern. For example is ```[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10] ->[1;2;3;4],[5;6;7],[8;9;10]```  _or_ ```[1;2;3;4],[5;6;7;8],[9;10]```? The tuple count balance rule is unclear.

Comment: @MartinFreedman It is unclear indeed. But often, when the specification has gaps, the choice is yours ;) In my answer all the remainder elements of the list go into the first place. for `n` elements and `m` bins, you get at most `m-1` such remainder elements and you could just as well try to distribute them equally.

Answer (score 5):

The most basic approach would be to walk over the list, process the rest of it recursively and then append the current element to one of the three returned lists. You will need to add an extra parameters `i` to the function to keep track of how far in the list you are (and then use this to determine where should the current elemnt go). The general structure in the most basic form is:

```
let split l =
  let length = List.length l
  let rec loop i l = 
    match l with 
    | [] -> 
        // Empty list just becomes a triple of empty lists
        [], [], []
    | x::xs ->
        // Process the rest of the list recursively. This 
        // gives us three lists containing the values from 'xs'
        let l1, l2, l3 = loop (i + 1) xs
        // Now comes the tricky bit. Here you need to figure out
        // whether 'x' should go into 'l1', 'l2' or 'l3'. 
        // Then you can append it to one of them using something like:
        l1, x::l2, l3
  // Walk over the list, starting with index 'i=0'
  loop 0 l
```

What to do about the tricky bit? I do not have a solution that works exactly as you wanted, but the following is close - it simply looks whether `i` is greater than 1/3 of the length or 2/3 of the length:

```
let split l =
  let length = List.length l
  let rec loop i l = 
    match l with 
    | [] -> [], [], []
    | x::xs ->
        let l1, l2, l3 = loop (i + 1) xs
        if i >= length / 3 * 2 then l1, l2, x::l3
        elif i >= length / 3 then l1, x::l2, l3
        else x::l1, l2, l3
  loop 0 l
```

This will always create groups of `length / 3` and put remaining elements in the last list:

```
split [1..3] // [1], [2], [3]
split [1..4] // [1], [2], [3; 4]
split [1..5] // [1], [2], [3; 4; 5]
split [1..6] // [1; 2], [3; 4], [5; 6]
```

You should be able to adapt this to the behaviour you need - there is some fiddly calculation that you need to do to figure out exactly where the cut-off points are, but that's a matter of getting the +/-1s right!

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for that in the `List` module.
You can test it easily in F# interactive (fsi).

```ml
let input = [1;2;3];;
let output = List.splitInto 3 input;;
```

> output;;
> val it : int list list = [[1]; [2]; [3]]

So it returns a list of lists.

If you want to do it by hand, you can still use other list functions (which might be good exercise in itself):

```ml
let manualSplitInto count list =
    let l = List.length list
    let n = l / count
    let r = l % count
    List.append
        [(List.take (n+r) list)]
        (List.unfold (fun rest ->
                      match rest with
                      | [] -> None
                      | _ ->  let taken = min n (List.length rest)
                              Some (List.take taken rest, List.skip taken rest))
                     (List.skip (n+r) list))
```

Here, List.unfold does the iteration (recursing) part for you.
So, if you really want to train working with recursive functions, you will end up writing your own `List.unfold` replacement or something more tailored to your concrete use case.

```ml
let pedestrianSplitInto count list =
    let l = List.length list
    let n = l / count
    let r = l % count
    let rec step rest acc =
        match rest with
        | [] -> acc
        | _ ->
            let taken = min n (List.length rest)
            step (List.skip taken rest) ((List.take taken rest) :: acc)
    List.rev (step (List.skip (n+r) list) [List.take (n+r) list])
```

Please observe how similar the implementation of function `step` is to the lambda given to `List.unfold` in `manualSplitInto`.

If you also do not want to use functions like `List.take` or `List.skip`, you will have to go even lower level and do element wise operations, such as:

```ml
let rec splitAtIndex index front rear =
    match index with
    | 0 -> (List.rev front, rear)
    | _ -> splitAtIndex (index - 1) ((List.head rear) :: front) (List.tail rear)
    
let stillLivingOnTreesSplitInto count list =
    let l = List.length list
    let n = l / count
    let r = l % count
    let rec collect result (front,rear) =
        match rear with
        | [] -> (front :: result)
        | _ -> collect (front :: result) (splitAtIndex n [] rear)
    let x = splitAtIndex (n+r) [] list
    collect [] x |> List.rev
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I wanted to practice matching with recursion instead of using functions that are already implemented in F#

Comment: @Alpha this is exactly what BitTickler was addressing in his answer. You want to manually implement splitInto or splitAt and can use recursion and pattern matching to do this, as in this answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you know it will always be triplets then this should work.

```
let xs = [1..7]
let n = List.length xs
let y = List.mapi (fun i x -> (x, 3 * i / n)) xs
List.foldBack (fun (x, i) (a,b,c) -> match i with 0 -> (x::a,b,c) | 1 -> (a,x::b,c) | 2 -> (a,b,x::c)) y (([],[],[]))
```